# I would like to have a dropdown list or checkboxes in Word that when selected, it shows certain tables in the document and hides the rest

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document (form) that contains 50 pages each page has a table.
I would like to give the user the ability to show certain tables and hide the rest after selecting from a dropdown list (or checkboxes).
Is this something that can be done from visual basics.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Select each of the tables and assign a bookmark to them and then use code such as the following to set the font as hidden for the .Range of each Bookmark

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Table1").Range.Font.Hidden = True

If the display of Hidden text is not enabled, the table will then no longer be visible

Comment: Thank you Doug, would it be possible please that I email you the document to give me related example

Comment: Yes, you can send it to me at dougrobbinsmvp[atsymbol]gmail[dot]com